# WCF service on IIS won't compile new version

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF Service that IIS is hosting.

I want to make a few small tweaks to it away from the office

So I have remote desktop in and made the changes to the interface and the cs file.. however IIS does not recompile a new version? I tried editing the `web.config` file as well (just adding some line spaces in)

I ran into this problem at the office so I have just been compiling it in VS and copying the whole directory across..

But shouldn't IIS compile it when changes are made, the same way it does for webpages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But Shouldnt IIS compile it when changes are made, the same way it does for webpages?

This will depend on which mode you decided to use:

- ASP.NET Web Site
- ASP.NET Web Application (precompiled)

If you choose the precompiled ASP.NET Web Application mode when creating the web service it is pretty useless to deploy any `.cs` files to your server. They will never be used, only the compiled assemblies in the `bin` folder.

As far as the Web Site mode is concerned, all `.cs` files go into the special `~/App_Code` `folder`.

You can read more about the differences between a [website and web application projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIS. It's pure ASP.NET.

Comment: ok thanks. i must have chosen the wrong choice from the get go.

Comment: You choose a precompiled Web Application when you created your web service in Visualo Studio.